# MySQL returning 0 rows where the rows have & symbol

Tags: php, mysql

Using PHP I'm trying to fetch records from MySQL using following syntax

```
select * from groups where groupname="Soya & Group";
```

Even after it exist in the table but still it is returning 0 rows.
Table have a lot of data which cannot me modified manually, rows where have & operator it is not returning any records.
Please help me with it.

```
$sql = "SELECT * from groups where groupname='Soya & Group';";
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {    
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    echo "<td>ID ".$row["id"]."</td>";
    echo "<td>ID ".$row["groupname"]."</td>";
        }

    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
```

Comment: Guess #1: The & is actually stored as `&amp;`in your table.

Comment: How `Soya & Group` saved in your database?

Comment: If you can't directly check your database to see how `Soya & Group` is stored, just do: `select * from groups` and log every single groupname to see how it is actually stored.

Comment: Yes Soya & Group is saved in the table. It is not &amp;

Comment: Ok, if so, can you please share the relevant php code related to that query? perhaps the error is somewhere else.

Comment: There is no error in the PHP code. It is running fine with other group name but returning 0 rows where the group names have & symbol.

Comment: Then post it if you are 100% aware that it has no errors. The SQL query has no errors aswell, the only possible guess related to the SQL query could've been, as VolkerK pointed out, the fact that & was stored as &amp; The other possible guess is the character encoding, but showing us more will be way more helpful instead of saying "It works". If it worked you wouldn't have been there, right? ;). Besides, as a side note, the code may be executing without returning anything, but that doesn't mean that the problem is not php related.

Comment: a) you're positive ANSI_QUOTES are off (because of the double-quoted string literal)? b)  `groupname LIKE 'Soya%Group'` does that return anything?

Comment: `$sql = "select * from groups where groupname='Soya & Group';";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "IDs".$row["id"];

    }
printf("\n");
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}`

Comment: That's rather unlikely because it will result in a php parse error because of said double-quotes.

Comment: That can't be the real php code else it will throw a parse error due to the "Soya & Group" inside of double-quotes.

Comment: I 've already tried single quotes. Even I tried in operator `where groupname in('Soya & Group')`

Comment: Please, show us the real code, i.e. code that you've tested, that in prinicple executes and that still produces the result in question. Please, don't let us guess what else MIGHT be wrong with the code.

Comment: Now your code snippet does not fetch any result record.

Comment: It is returning records but the problem is with those rows which have & symbol.

Comment: The code snippet you've posted does not fetch records. There's no call to any of the fetch-functions/method in that snippet <-> what is `$row`?

Comment: VolkerK: It is running fine. There is no problem with the PHP code.

Comment: I've fixed it. See the below comment. The query is not even running with PMA

Comment: Honestly? Now the code is even worse. For starters just try to explain what `$result->num_rows` in the very first line of the snippet is. And then how the while loop is supposed to work <-> what is $result at this point? edit:I have a bad feeling that there's another (outer-) query and in the end the solution will be a JOIN query.

Comment: I've copied the code from http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp
Well, let it be about the code. It is not even returning from PHPMyAdmin query window using `SELECT * from groups where groupname="Soya & Group";`

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

One doubts very much that the ampersand is the problem.  But, you can easily test for it using `like`:

```
select *
from groups
where groupname like 'Soya _ Group';
```

The `_` character will match anything.

More likely, there is a subtle problem with the data in your database.  See if one of these return anything:

```
where groupname like '%Soya _ Group%';
where groupname like '%Soya&Group%';
where lower(groupname) like '%soya%group%';
```

A lot of different things *could* be happening.  For instance, your default collation could be case sensitive and the values could really be `Soya & group`.  There are other possibilities as well.  Once you get *some* match, you can investigate the actual values to determine what is happening.

Comment: I'm using PMA and I tried run the same query from the query window by copying the exact value from the PMA but still it is returning 0 rows. The exact value stored in the row is as same I am trying to fetch.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the support. Well, I replaced **&** with **and** in the MySQL table using following query

```
UPDATE groups set groupname=REPLACE(groupname,'&','and');
```

This query solved my problem.